# format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type 'unsigned long'

Tags: objective-c, c, arrays, long-integer, unsigned

I'm newbie in obj-c .
How to fix it?
format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type 'unsigned long'

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    const char *words[4] = {"aardvark","abacus","allude","zygote"};
    int wordCount = 4;
    int i;

    for(i=0;i<wordCount;i++){
        NSLog(@"%s comprises %d chars", words[i], strlen(words[i]));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`strlen()` returns a `size_t`, which can be 32-bit or 64-bit, depending on the used
architecture.

The correct format to print a `size_t` is `%zu`:

```
NSLog(@"%s comprises %zu chars", words[i], strlen(words[i]));
```

See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/printf.html
for "z" and other length modifiers:

- **z**
  Specifies that a following [...] conversion specifier applies to a `size_t` or the corresponding signed integer type argument;

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the good format in the `NSLog` (which seems to use the same format as `printf` and cie):

```
NSLog(@"%s comprises %zu chars", words[i], strlen(words[i]));
```

Or you can cast the return of `strlen`:

```
NSLog(@"%s comprises %d chars", words[i], (int)strlen(words[i]));
```

Comment: @MartinR Sorry, I begin with a quick answer which was not entirely correct, then fix it and re fix it (thanks Eric). And yeah, finnaly it's quite the same and i'm sorry ... but who cares ?

Comment: Sorry for over-reacting. I have deleted my comment.